# Package repository down, how to relocate?

Tags: packages, miktex, repositories

I would like to use the function of TeXnicCenter 1.0, where is automatically downloads missing packages used. The problem is, that the repository it wants to download from does not exist anymore (the one on piotrkosoft.net).

How do I get TeXnicCenter to try with another repository?

Comment: Hi imzs, Welcome to tex exchange! I think you might be a little confused- TeXnicCenter does not manage the packages; if you're on Windows then it will be handled by either MiKTeX or TeXlive, depending on which distribution you installed. Can you update us with which distribution you are using?

Comment: Hi! Sure I am confused. :) I have just started with LaTeX. I'm using MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: You can change the repository in the miktex package manager. But you should be aware that texniccenter often disturbs the on-the-fly-installation.

Comment: In TXC 1.0 there is a bug regarding on-the-fly-installation from MiKex. It is fixed in TXC 2.0, which is officially in alpha status, but works for me with some small problems not relevant for TeX output routine (I would consider it in beta status …).

Answer (score 11):

Use the "packages shall be installed from a directory" option instead.

Download the packages you want from 
https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages
to a directory on your own system.

Also download the files

```
miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma
miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma
```

so that the directory is recognized as a package repository (change 2.9 to the relevant version number, presumably).

Comment: This worked perfectly 2 years later (note the CTAN mirror path listed didn't work, but [this](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages) did).

Comment: @jedwards many thanks - I fixed the URL

Comment: 3 years later: worked like a charm!

Answer (score 7):

To change the repository in MiKTeX you need to open the package manager. Then go to `Repository > Change Package Repository`.

[image]

Then you have to choose the option "Packages shall be installed from the Internet".

[image]

After this you should be able to choose a new repository.

[image]

Comment: I don't know why this answer got and upvoted. If the repository is down, then the 3rd picture would only say repository is down and wouldn't be able to retrieve other repositories(at least this is the problem that I am getting)

Comment: @SarpKaya It seems that at the moment _no_ repository can be reached through the MiKTeX package manager ("The MiKTeX package repository is down for maintenance.").

Comment: Yes I know, but I think the question is asking, how to change the repository for the moments like this, rather than other times when it is actually working.

Comment: @SarpKaya No, the question is about a specific repository, i.e. piotrkosoft.net.